# MVC 5 Route Url Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `UserController` with the following actions: `Register`, `Login`, and `UserProfile`.

So as for those actions, I want the URL's to be:

> `Register` - /User/Register
>
> `Login` - /User/Login
>
> `UserProfile` - /User/{username} (This route will take control only if
>   no action was found)

So this is how my RouteConfig.cs looks like:

```
// Default:
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { area = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication" }
);

// User Profile - Default:
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UserProfileDefault",
    url: "User/{username}",
    defaults: new { area = "", controller = "User", action = "UserProfile" },
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication" }
);
```

I need that the route for `UserProfile` will take control only if there's no action in the `UserController` to take control.

Unfortunately, my code is not working, I get a 404 for navigating 
 to the `UserProfile` route, but all the other UserController actions are working.

I also moved the `UserProfile` route to the top and still not working, I tried everything, nothing seems to work.

Comment: what does the incoming parameter look like in the Action?  Could you post it?  And you are going straight to /User without using anything after it?  Did you try User/MyUserName to see if it would hit the action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All 3 url you have shown match the first route (which means any url that contains between 0 and 3 segments), and your 3rd url (say `../User/OShai`) goes the `OShai()` method of `UserController` which does not exist.

You need to define specific routes in the correct order (the first match wins)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Register",
    url: "/User/Register",
    defaults: new { area = "", controller = "User", action = "Register" },
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "/User/Login",
    defaults: new { area = "", controller = "User", action = "Login" },
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication" }
);
// Match any url where the 1st segment is 'User' and the 2nd segment is not 'Register' or 'Login'
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profile",
    url: "/User/{username}",
    defaults: new { area = "", controller = "User", action = "UserProfile" },
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication" }
);
// Default
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { area = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication" }
);
```

Where the `Profile` route will match

```
public ActionResult UserProfile(string username)
```

in `UserController`

Alternatively, you could delete the `Register` and `Login` routes, and create a constraint for the `Profile` route to check to the 2nd segment matches "Register" or "Login", and if so, return false so it then matches the `Default` route.

```
public class UserNameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        List<string> actions = new List<string>() { "register", "login" };
        // Get the username from the url
        var username = values["username"].ToString().ToLower();
        // Check for a match
        return !actions.Any(x => x.ToLower() == username);
    }
}
```

and then modify the `Profile` route to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profile",
    url: "/User/{username}",
    defaults: new { area = "", controller = "User", action = "UserProfile" },
    constraints: new { username = new UserNameConstraint() }
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication" }
);
```